# Will the internal data be deleted when package is renamed

Tags: android

In android, apps keep their internal data (such as files, preferences, databases) in some folder "Android/data/com/APP_NAME/" and its subfolders.

Apparently, if I rename app from APP_NAME to NEW_NAME, new folder ("Android/data/com/NEW_NAME/") will be created and therefore no data from previous app location will be accessible. But will it be kept or deleted?

I point out that I am speaking about package renaming, not app deleting, while, as I tested, some configuration of renamed app stays.

And so, consequent question: if I rename app from NEW_NAME to APP_NAME back - will package folder (and all files in it) be accessible again - or overwritten?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I point out that I am speaking about package renaming, not app deleting, while, as I tested, some configuration of renamed app stays.

Sure. The application ID ("package") is the unique identifier of an app, both on-device and in distribution channels like the Play Store. When the user installs the app with the renamed package, the old app remains installed.

IOW, what you call "package renaming" is really "writing a completely different app". The fact that the different app has some elements in common with the original does not matter. If the application IDs differ, they are different apps.

> Apparently, if I rename app from APP_NAME to NEW_NAME, new folder ("Android/data/com/NEW_NAME/") will be created and therefore no data from previous app location will be accessible. But will it be kept or deleted?

That depends entirely on the user. If the user leaves the APP_NAME app installed, the files will remain. If the user uninstalls the APP_NAME app, the files will be removed.

> if I rename app from NEW_NAME to APP_NAME back - will package folder (and all files in it) be accessible again - or overwritten?

If you mean "if the user installs a new version of APP_NAME", that once again depends on whether the user left the old APP_NAME app installed (if so, the files will still be there) or if the user uninstalled it (if so, the files will be removed).

Answer (score 0):

The data which is created by the user will stay in the appropriate folder until the user himself deletes it.
If you rename the app, yes new folder will be created, and if you again make the name as previous name, the old data would be again accessible.

**Still you can go through below steps for Package Rename**

You can rename your package any any point of time from Android Studio.

You can follow the below steps to rename the package :

1. Click on Gear Icon on the Project view's Tool bar and deselect Hide Empty middle packages. After this all the package folder will split.
2. Right Click on the folder which needs to be renamed, and Click on Refactor -> Rename and give the new package name and click on **Rename Package** button.

The Folder name will be changed and **no items will be deleted**.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I think he's talking about the user data on a previous installed version;

Comment: @PranaySoni I am talking about data on android device itself, not about developement and project files in Android Studio.

Comment: @MilTy I gave answer for Android device data only.